# Purr::map2 filtering on multiple criteria

Tags: r, purrr

I have generated a series of random walks, by individual, that move around a bounded arena (data.frame fishmoves). Within this arena, there are grid squares of interest (data.frame ants, with x and y coordinates for the boxes). I would like to filter fishmoves to only include points within the grid squares of interest. Then I would like to calculate the number of individuals and amount of timesteps that each individual spends in each box.

**Solved** I am hitting a snag on the filtering. I am using purr::map2 to pass the filter criteria from ants, but it doesn't work when I call all four parameters--instead returning null. I made sure (data.frame tester) that there are actual values to be found, so it must be that I'm doing something wrong in the call. **end Solved**

Which prevents me from the next step, splitting by ant and summarizing by individual and # of timesteps.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
library(tidyverse)

n.times<-1000
OUT <-data.frame(time=vector("numeric", n.times), x.a = vector("numeric", n.times),y.a = vector("numeric", n.times))

walker <- function(n.times,
                   xlim=c(0,40),
                   ylim=c(0,20),
                   start=c(0,0),
                   stepsize=c(1,1)) {
  ## extract starting point
  x <- start[1]
  y <- start[2]

  for (i in 1:n.times) {
    repeat {
      ## pick jump sizes
      xi <- stepsize[1]*sample(rnorm(n = n.times, mean = 0, sd = .5),1)
      yi <- stepsize[2]*sample(rnorm(n = n.times, mean = 0, sd = .5),1)
      ## new candidate locations
      newx <- x+xi
      newy <- y+yi
      ## IF new locations are within bounds, then
      ##    break out of the repeat{} loop (otherwise
      ##    try again)
      if (newx>xlim[1] && newx<xlim[2] &&
          newy>ylim[1] && newy<ylim[2]) break
    }
    ## set new location to candidate location
    x <- newx
    y <- newy
    OUT[i,"time"]<-i
    OUT[i,"x.a"] <-x
    OUT[i, "y.a"] <-y
  }
  return(OUT)
}


#generate fake fish
fish<-data.frame(fish=as.character(letters[1:10]))

#apply walker to fake fish
fishmoves <- fish %>% 
  mutate(data= map(fish,~walker(n.times))) %>% 
  unnest(data)


#ants <- data.frame(ant=c("a", "b"),x.min=seq(from=2, to = 38, by= 4)),x.max=c(1,4),y.min=c(0,2), y.max=c(1,3)) 
ants <- data.frame(ant=LETTERS[1:16]) %>% 
  bind_cols(x.min=c(seq(from=4, to = 32, by= 4),seq(from=4, to = 32, by= 4)),
            y.min=c(rep(4,each=8),rep(12,each=8))) %>% 
  mutate(x.max=x.min+2,
         y.max=y.min+2) %>% 
  group_by(ant) 


#filter fishmoves based on the filter parameters - works separately for both x and y

ant_fish1 <- map2(ants$x.min, ants$x.max, ~ fishmoves %>%
         filter(between(x.a, ..1[1], ..2[1])) )

ant_fish2 <- map2(ants$y.min, ants$y.max, ~ fishmoves %>%
                    filter(between(y.a, ..1[1], ..2[1])) )  

#test to demonstrate that there are individuals that meet the joint criteria
tester <- fishmoves %>% filter (between(x.a, ants$x.min[1], ants$x.max[1]) & between(y.a, ants$y.min[1], ants$y.max[1]))

#### switched map2 to pmap

ant_fish <- pmap(list(ants$x.min, ants$x.max, ants$y.min, ants$y.max), ~ fishmoves %>%
                    filter(between(x.a, ..1[1], ..2[1]) & between(y.a, ..3[1], ..4[1])) )  

#conceptual approach? does not work...
ant_fish <- ants %>% nest(ant_loc = c(x.min, x.max, y.min, y.max)) %>% 
 pmap(list(ants$x.min, ants$x.max, ants$y.min, ants$y.max), ~ fishmoves %>%
                    filter(between(x.a, ..1[1], ..2[1]) & between(y.a, ..3[1], ..4[1])) ) %>% 
  group_by(fish) %>% 
  summarise(counts=n())
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you can't use map2 like that. The 2 in map2 means that the function you're using to map must accept 2 (and only 2) arguments, but you want to use a function that accepts 4 arguments. The mapping function that does what you want is called [pmap](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html).

Instead of this...

```
#filter returns null
ant_fish3 <- map2(ants$x.min, ants$x.max, ants$y.min, ants$y.max, ~ fishmoves %>%
                    filter(between(x.a, ..1[1], ..2[1]) & between(y.a, ..3[1], ..4[1])) )
```

You'd use this...

```
ant_fish3 <- pmap(list(ants$x.min, ants$x.max, ants$y.min, ants$y.max), function(one, two, three, four) { 
    fishmoves %>%
        filter(between(x.a, one[1], two[1]) & between(y.a, three[1], four[1])) })
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved problem 1, I found the documentation confusing on that point. Still haven't figured out how to do part 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out. This seems to generate what I am looking for:
1) filter the movement data set to the spatial limits
2) generate a summary of the number of individuals and total time/individual

```
ant_fish <- ants %>% group_by(ant) %>% 
  mutate(data=pmap(list(x.min, x.max, y.min, y.max), ~ fishmoves %>%
         filter(between(x.a, ..1[1], ..2[1]) & between(y.a, ..3[1], ..4[1]))  %>% 
  group_by(fish) %>% 
  summarise(counts=n())))
```